# error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘lessthen_predictable_t?

Tags: c

Following this tutorial:
http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/7.-The%20Heap.html

I have the following errors:

```
source/ordered_array.c: In function ‘insert_ordered_array’:
source/ordered_array.c:43:67: error: expected identifier before ‘[’ token
source/ordered_array.c:43:67: error: too few arguments to function ‘array->less_than’
make: *** [obj/ordered_array.o] Error 1
```

From my compiler. I don't get any of it as I have followed the tutorial fully.

here are the files associated:

ordered_array.h:

```
// ordered_array.h -- Interface for creating, inserting and deleting
//                    from ordered arrays.
//                    Written for JamesM's kernel development tutorials.

#ifndef ORDERED_ARRAY_H
#define ORDERED_ARRAY_H

#include "common.h"

/**
   This array is insertion sorted - it always remains in a sorted state (between calls).
   It can store anything that can be cast to a void* -- so a u32int, or any pointer.
**/
typedef void* type_t;
/**
    A predicate should return nonzero if the first argument is less than the second.  Else 
    it should return zero.
**/
typedef s8int (*lessthan_predicate_t)(type_t,type_t);
typedef struct
{
    type_t *array;
    u32int size;
    u32int max_size;
    lessthan_predicate_t less_than;
} ordered_array_t;

/**
   A standard less than predicate.
**/
s8int standard_lessthan_predicate(type_t a, type_t b);

/**
   Create an ordered array.
**/
ordered_array_t create_ordered_array(u32int max_size, lessthan_predicate_t less_than);
ordered_array_t place_ordered_array(void *addr, u32int max_size, lessthan_predicate_t  less_than);

/**
   Destroy an ordered array.
**/
void destroy_ordered_array(ordered_array_t *array);

/**
   Add an item into the array.
**/
void insert_ordered_array(type_t item, ordered_array_t *array);

/**
   Lookup the item at index i.
**/
type_t lookup_ordered_array(u32int i, ordered_array_t *array);

/**
   Deletes the item at location i from the array.
**/
void remove_ordered_array(u32int i, ordered_array_t *array);

#endif // ORDERED_ARRAY_H
```

ordered_arrays.c:

```
// ordered_array.c -- Implementation for creating, inserting and deleting
//                    from ordered arrays.
//                    Written for JamesM's kernel development tutorials.

#include "ordered_array.h"

s8int standard_lessthan_predicate ( type_t a, type_t b )
{
return ( a < b ) ? 1:0;
}

ordered_array_t create_ordered_array ( u32int max_size, lessthan_predicate_t less_than     )
{
ordered_array_t to_ret;
to_ret.array = ( void* ) kmalloc ( max_size * sizeof ( type_t ) ) ;
memset ( to_ret.array, 0, max_size*sizeof ( type_t ) );
to_ret.size = 0;
to_ret.max_size = max_size;
to_ret.less_than = less_than;
return to_ret;
}

ordered_array_t place_ordered_array ( void *addr, u32int max_size, lessthan_predicate_t   less_than )
{
ordered_array_t to_ret;
to_ret.array = ( type_t *) addr;
memset ( to_ret.array, 0, max_size*sizeof ( type_t ) );
to_ret.size = 0;
to_ret.max_size = max_size;
to_ret.less_than = less_than;
return to_ret;
}

void destroy_ordered_array ( ordered_array_t *array )
{
// kfree ( array -> array );
}

void insert_ordered_array ( type_t item, ordered_array_t *array )
{
ASSERT ( array -> less_than );
u32int iterator = 0;
---------------------------------------Faulting Line------------------------------------
while ( iterator < array -> size && array -> less_than ( array ->[iterator], item )    )
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    iterator++;
if ( iterator == array -> size ) // just add at the end of the array.
    array -> array [array -> size++] = item;
else
{
    type_t tmp = array -> array[iterator];
    array -> array[iterator] = item;
    while ( iterator < array -> size )
    {
        iterator++;
        type_t tmp2 = array -> array[iterator];
        array -> array[iterator] = tmp;
        tmp = tmp2;
    }
    array -> size++;
}
}

type_t lookup_order_array ( u32int i, ordered_array_t *array )
{
ASSERT ( i < array -> size );
return array -> array [i];
}

void remove_ordered_array ( u32int i, ordered_array_t *array )
{
while ( i < array -> size )
{
    array -> array[i] = array -> array[i+1];
    i++;
}
array -> size--;
}
```

Any idea's why I'm getting the compile errors?

Answer (score 1):

`lessthen_predictable_t` is not defined anywhere.

`array ->[iterator]` is wrong. At a guess it should probably be `array->array[iterator]` ?

Comment: After changing lessthen_predictable_t to lessthan_predicate_t, I have a new error list although this time smaller, any idea's?

Comment: This looks weird : array ->[iterator], -> and [] ? what do you think this is doing?

Comment: updated OP with the faulting line.

And where is the 'error' you've noticed?